# Detox - Android / iOS - Cannot run the same test on android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, detox

I had been trying to find information about this error that I will post below, I did all the configurations and made research, I am using the latest version of everything.
But since I am new to Detox, I was assuming that the test written for iOS works for Android, if so please ignore and please provide details on how to adapt.

Basically the error I am getting is this:

```
detox[40905] INFO:  [test.js] configuration="android.emu.debug" reportSpecs=true readOnlyEmu=false useCustomLogger=true forceAdbInstall=false DETOX_START_TIMESTAMP=1588961953280 node_modules/.bin/jest --config e2e/config.json '--testNamePattern=^((?!:ios:).)*$' --maxWorkers 1 "e2e"
detox[40909] INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:49577...
detox[40909] ERROR: [DetoxExportWrapper.js/DETOX_INIT_ERROR]
 DetoxRuntimeError: Failed to run application on the device

HINT: Most likely, your tests have timed out and called detox.cleanup() while it was waiting for "ready" message (over WebSocket) from the instrumentation process.
    at EmulatorDriver._getInstrumentationCrashError (/Users/brunosoko/Documents/appExam/node_modules/detox/src/devices/drivers/android/AndroidDriver.js:165:12)
    at EmulatorDriver.instrumentationCloseListener (/Users/brunosoko/Documents/appExam/node_modules/detox/src/devices/drivers/android/AndroidDriver.js:128:67)
    at EmulatorDriver._terminateInstrumentation (/Users/brunosoko/Documents/appExam/node_modules/detox/src/devices/drivers/android/AndroidDriver.js:156:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/brunosoko/Documents/appExam/node_modules/detox/src/devices/drivers/android/AndroidDriver.js:274:7) {
  name: 'DetoxRuntimeError'
}
detox[40909] INFO:  Example: should show login screen after tap on Sign in button
```

I do not know if it's a bug or something that I am doing wrong.

Here's my `package.json`

```
  "detox": {
    "specs": "",
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "/Users/brunosoko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppExam-cwpqhbjlywwwihfaazprzmynvoym/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appExam.app",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 11"
      },
      "android.emu.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "/Users/brunosoko/Documents/AppExam/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
        "type": "android.emulator",
        "name": "Pixel_3_API_R_2"
      }
    },
    "test-runner": "jest"
  },
```

Comment: The other detail to add here is that, as you can see I am using it as black box testing tool, I do not have the source code of the app on the same repo as the tests

Comment: Could you please provide logs from the emulator device?

Comment: Here's the log: https://gist.github.com/bmsoko/db1d13cb46ae9cf4aa9acc6632f6bc81

Comment: What's your application's package name (e.g. com.android.test)? Also, could you please retry using the latest Detox? We've applied an important permissions related fix, which your logs hint at.

Comment: SORRY! I was making a huge mistake! I was not doing the correct setup of the android app, I did not build it with `./gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug` after that is working! Thanks @d4vidi

Comment: Glad to know you have it sorted out. May I ask what _did_ you do for app building? I'm asking so as to try to improve Ux (i.e. make it easier to understand for future devs)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the wrong path for DetoxTest.java file. '/com' subdirectory was missing. For the package name:

```
de.dummy.example
```

it should be

```
android\app\src\androidTest\java\com\de\dummy\example
```

and not:

```
android\app\src\androidTest\java\de\dummy\example
```